# How to Enabled Virtualization on Window 10 By Command Line or Power Shell?

Tags: powershell, command-line, virtualization

[image]

I want set all HyperRequirement**** to **true** make sure i have enabled in BIOS Setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set those properties from Powershell - you need to find the appropriate settings for Windows and/or your BIOS that relate to virtualization and enable them

For `HyperVRequirementDataExecutionPreventionAvailable`, you need a processor that supports Data Execution Prevention, and it must be enabled:

[image: DEP]

For `HyperVRequirementSecondLevelAddressTranslation`, you need a processor that supports Second Level Address Translation. To my knowledge, this is not a configurable setting - you have it or you don't

For `HyperVRequirementVirtualizationFirmwareEnabled`, you will have to ensure that virtualization is enabled correctly in your BIOS.

For `HyperVRequirementVMMonitorModeExtensions`, your processor must support VT-x or AMD-V, and it must be enabled in your BIOS.